# Using Windows Automation how can i place a listbox on a screen specific location

Tags: c#, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

Lets say I have a `listbox` created from code, now I want to place this `listbox` on location `x,z` without creating a winform.

How can I do that using Windows Automation without having the listbox contained in a winform?

Comment: Windows UI Automation does not help creating forms or controls. It's meant to automate existing UIs.